# error al correr run-andoroid con REACT-NATIVE

Tags: javascript, react-native

consio lo siguientes errores los cuales , no se como podria resolverlos
ya que soy un principiante en el tema de aplicaciones reactivas. o con react.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no consigo que mi movil corra la app ,
pero esta corriendo en mi servidor react, o eso da a pensar el comando react-native start

debido a que en mi equipo consulto en el navegador, y me arroja una respuesta http.
como la siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

agradezco la ayuda de antemano.

Comment: La estás corriendo desde tu Mobil? de ser así, cuéntame cómo la instalaste en el mismo

Comment: en mi maquina instale, node.js, python, jdk y sdk de java, y siguiente con andorid studio haces el trabajo de colocar el proyecto inicial de react native en tu mobil. aqui te dejo un enlace de lo que hice @GermanAlzate.

https://shift.infinite.red/getting-started-with-react-native-development-on-windows-90d85a72ae65#.3s3x751kn

el unico detalle que esta en ingles, y al traducirlo con el navegador no te de la traduccion exacta.

Comment: Vale te comprendo, lo que quiero saber es si estás usando tu propio Mobil, o si estás usando una máquina virtual para hacer el proceso? El link que me muestras te explica como hacerlo en una maquina virtual o emulador, mientras en tu descripción hablas de tu mobil

Comment: en los dos casos me muestra el mismo error, mobile y en el emulador de android.